# Why am I getting this message printed twice after the first command is entered by the user?

Tags: c, printf

I already wrote all the code, everything's correct, but for some reason, the message "Enter command or enter 'Q' to quit:" gets printed twice after entering the first command.

I just need help figuring out why that message keeps getting printed out twice. I've worked on this with my tutor, and we can't seem to figure out why that message gets printed twice after the first input/command. Any help would he greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
int main() {
   studentType s[MAX_STUDENTS];
   teacherType t[MAX_TEACHERS];
   char input[MAX_NAME];
   int numS, numT;
   char command;
   FILE * out;

   numS = readStudentInfo(s); /* Number of students equals size of array. */
   numT = readTeacherInfo(t); /* Number of teachers equals size of array. */

   out = fopen("log.out", "w");

   while (command != 'Q') {
      printf("Enter command or enter 'Q' to quit:\n");
      scanf("%c", &command);

      if (command == 'S') {
         scanf("%s", input);
         fprintf(out, "-->%c %s\n", command, input);
         getStudentInfo(s, t, input, numS, numT, out);
      }

      if (command == 'T') {
         scanf("%s", input);
         fprintf(out, "-->%c %s\n", command, input);
         findStudents(s, t, input, numS, numT, out);
      }

      if (command == 'G') {
         scanf("%s", input);
         fprintf(out, "-->%c %s\n", command, input);
         getGradeList(s, t, atoi(input), numS, numT, out);
      }

      if (command == 'L') {
         scanf("%s", input);
         fprintf(out, "-->%c %s\n", command, input);
         findGradeTeachers(s, t, atoi(input), numS, numT, out);
      }

   }

   if (command == 'Q') {
      fprintf(out, "-->%c\n", command);
      fclose(out);
      return 0;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

And here's what I get when I run the program:

[image]

As you can see, the only time the message "Enter..." isn't printed twice is upon start up, why is this happening? Thanks ahead of time for everyone who answers!

Comment: you should use fflush(stdin); before scanf statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space at the beginning of each string format of the `scanf()`:

```
scanf(" %c", &command);

scanf(" %s", input);
```

In your code, the newline is catched in the `scanf("%c", &command);` and you have to avoid the catch of the newlines by adding space at the beginning of the string format of the scanf

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%c",&command);
```

if you input a character say 'L' and press enter key to the above scanf. Only character 'L' is read into command variable and still 'enter key' is in stdin. And hence next time for scanf the above enter key is feed as input and it is ignored by your code.

so it is good practice to use a space before `%c`

```
scanf(" %c",&command);
```

you can also use `fflush();` before scanf google about `fflush()`